# Nonetype has no Attribute error in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

Facing `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'role_access'` when role is `None`. How to prevent this error by return just *empty []* ?

```py
class AccessListSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):
        def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.access.code


class MyInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    approvers = ApproverSerializer(many=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(source="user.email")
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    domain = DomainSerializer()
    role = RoleSerializer()
    access = AccessListSerializer(
        source='role.role_access',many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = ['email', 'username', 'role',
                'domain', 'approvers', 'access']
```

For more information you'd better know that `Role` field is a null field.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Can you show me the code of the `RoleSerializer` and the models also?

Comment: AttributeError at /leavetracker/employee/me/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'role_access'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/leavetracker/employee/me/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'role_access'
Exception Location: C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\leave_tracker_backend-1STK9NyG\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py, line 97, in get_attribute
Python Executable: C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\leave_tracker_backend-1STK9NyG\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.6

Comment: class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_delete = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'code', 'is_delete']

Comment: class Role(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4)

Comment: try adding `"id"` to MyInfoSerializer fields attribute, what would happen? @mohammedfayeez